# How to set tabBackground of TabLayout circle indicator

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have a `Tablayout` as onboarding indicators. I want to set the colors of indicators when onboarding background change from dark to light :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/onboarding_tab_selector"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    />
```

**This is the background :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/onboarding_selected_tab"
        android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/onboarding_default_tab"/>
</selector>
```

**I created a new light background :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/onboarding_selected_tab_light"
        android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/onboarding_default_tab_light"/>
</selector>
```

**Dark screen**

[image]

**Light screen**

[image]

**I tried :**

```
tabLayout.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.onboarding_tab_selector_light));
```

**And :**

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(R.drawable.onboarding_tab_selector_light);
```

It is not working, as you can see in **the result**

[image].